# Как получить путь к картинке, которая находится в базе данных. (Django, Jinja, HTML)

Tags: html, django, img, jinja2, django-model

Передо мной стоит задача: Вставить в тэг img картинку. В моделях приложения я прописал:

```
  class Product(models.Model):
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/")
```

Теперь, заходя в админку, и заполняя таблицу картинку, в она должна добавиться в БД(я новокек, не думаю что прям в БД, но тут буду говорить так). И вот теперь, эту картинку мне нужно вывести в HTML. Я пишу:

```
{% for m in meals %}
        <img class="meal__img" src="{{m.photo}}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

Вставить фото таким образом это то, что сразу пришло на ум. Разумеется, данный способ не сработал, ведь нужен сам путь, а как его вытянуть - я не знаю. Выручайте (п.с, я не вставлял тот код, который не относится к вопросу, опыта у меня нету, может что-то важное я упустил, прошу прощения)

Comment: `{ m.photo.url }` будет вставлять **url** картинки.

Answer (score 0):

Отлично заработал вариант пользователя "Sherlock", с небольшой поправкой. Вот такой код уже работает:

```
{% for m in meals %}
        <img class="meal__img" src="{{ m.photo.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```